# How to right align an image in flexbox without justify-content?

Tags: html, css, email, flexbox, alignment

I'm making an html email and I have some text and an image in a flexbox. I want to right align the image irrespective of the amount of text on the left. I used "justify-content: space-between" initially which would normally do the trick but that's not working with G-Mail. Any alternatives?

Comment: Would float: right work on G-mail. float was designed particularly to allow text to float around an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are using the table format for the e-mail part. And FYI, Gmail does not support flexbox.
To make the image align to the right, apply `text-align: right;` in the parent element of the `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to align the text and the image on the same line but image will align on the left and the image on the right...
Try this:

```css
h3 /* (or whatever element you are using for your text) */
{
    text-align:left;
    display:inline;
}
    
img{
    display:inline; float right;
}
```